# The effect of a parameters on an espicific equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading in a [paper](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/cin/2011/217987/) , and I faced the below equation. You don't have actually to look to the paper , but if my question seems to be unclear and one wants to look on the source without asking me to be more clarify.

[image: Equation 1]

where Ws and W0 are vectors and Σs  is a covariance matrix. 
 it's says about the parameters  λ 1 , λ 2 :

> The parameters λ 1 and λ 2 enable us to make a trade-off between the
>   vector W0 and Vs. For a high value of λ 1 and a
>   low value of λ 2 , the vector w 0 is forced to zero . When λ 2 is high and λ 1 low, the vector v s is
>   forced to zero . Furthermore, one
>   can also perform regularization by choosing both λ 1 and λ 2 high.

My question is how a high value of  λ 1  will make vector W0  approach to zero ?

Comment: It's hard to say without more context, but: you want to maximize that expression, so you want a small denominator.  If $\lambda_1$ is big, then you want $w_0$ close to $0$ so that the denominator stays small.

Comment: @AdamSaltz that's simply the question ! , just copy the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to maximize that expression, so you want a small denominator.  If $\lambda_1$ is big, then you want $w_0$ close to $0$ so that the denominator stays small.